# How to debug PyQt5 threads in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pyqt5

I am right now developing a PyQT5 application an use multithreading to avoid freezing of the GUI. Unfortuneately the Visual Studio Code debugger does not stop on breakpoints inside the executed thread. I tried all suggestions from the following page without fixing the problem. https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/428. I think VS Code switched debugger from ptvsd to debugpy so all the suggestions do not hold any more. Maybe somebody has an idea how to fix this issue.

```
import time
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel


class Worker(QObject):
    sig_msg = pyqtSignal(str)  # message to be shown to user

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        self.sig_msg.emit('Hello from inside the thread!')

        result = 1 + 1
        result2 = 1 + 2


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Thread Example")

        form_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(form_layout)
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.button_start_threads = QPushButton("Start")
        self.button_start_threads.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)

        self.label = QLabel()

        form_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        form_layout.addWidget(self.button_start_threads)

        QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')

        self.__threads = None

    def start_threads(self):
        self.__threads = []

        worker = Worker()
        thread = QThread()
        thread.setObjectName('thread')
        self.__threads.append((thread, worker))  # need to store worker too otherwise will be gc'd
        worker.moveToThread(thread)

        worker.sig_msg.connect(self.label.setText)

        thread.started.connect(worker.work)
        thread.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    form = MyWidget()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can reproduce the error by setting a breakpoint at self.sig_msg.emit('Hello from inside the thrad!') in my case the debugger does not stop at this position. I use VS Code Version 1.65.2. The code is taken from the post mentioned above.

Answer (score 12):

I have recently experienced the same issue with VS Code and PyQt5. Following the advice at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_troubleshooting, I was able to hit the breakpoint in your example code by importing `debugpy` and adding `debugpy.debug_this_thread()` in the work method e.g.

```py
def work(self):
    debugpy.debug_this_thread()
    self.sig_msg.emit('Hello from inside the thread!')

    result = 1 + 1
    result2 = 1 + 2
```

Hopefully that can help others facing the same issue.

Comment: For QThread - just to make it explicit: the call to 'debugpy.debug_this_thread()' must be made at the start of the thread run() where you have placed a break point.